# How to limit H2 datetime records to last 5 minutes?

Tags: sql, h2

I looked at the other postings here on SO, but didn't see on that fixed my issue. If I can't do what I need to do in H2 SQL, I can process the ResultSet in code, but I'd prefer to have SQL handle it.

The problem:  Client has an "ERRDATE" field with this format: 2023-03-05 11:00:00.000000000

Requirement: I need to be able to be able to select all records in only the last five minutes.

Here is the closest SQL I've managed:

```
SELECT * FROM LOG where ERRDATE > DATEADD('MINUTE',-5, CURRENT_DATE())
```

This query does bring up the correct record, but not just within the last 5 minutes.  I ran this query 30 minutes later and it still brings up the same record.

I tried DATEDIFF, TIMESTAMPDIFF but none of those worked.

So, if possible, how do I get the records for only the last 5 minutes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Timestamps do not have a format. Can you confirm what's the data type of `ERRDATE`? You should store it as TIMESTAMP, not VARCHAR.

Comment: Works perfectly well for me: `create table t (id int, ts timestamp);
insert into t (id, ts) values (1, timestampadd(minute, -10, current_timestamp()));
insert into t (id, ts) values (2, timestampadd(minute, -8, current_timestamp()));
insert into t (id, ts) values (3, timestampadd(minute, -6, current_timestamp()));
insert into t (id, ts) values (4, timestampadd(minute, -4, current_timestamp()));
insert into t (id, ts) values (5, timestampadd(minute, -2, current_timestamp()));
select * from t where ts > timestampadd(minute, -5, current_timestamp());`.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. In my case, since this syntax was implemented through a DBF JDBC driver, I had to put minute in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If `ERRDATE` has a `TIMESTAMP` data type, you usually should use

```sql
ERRDATE > LOCALTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
```

in modern version of H2.

If it has a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` should be used instead:

```sql
ERRDATE > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm using a JDBC driver for DBFs (yes, those still, barely, exist). It uses H2, but apparently not "exactly". However your approach is very helpful. The "INTERVAL" wasn't supported in this "H2" JDBC driver, but this is the general idea that worked.